# What is best Ruby Class design / pattern for this scenario?

Tags: mysql, ruby, oop

I currently have this class for scraping products from a single retailer website using Nokogiri.  XPath, CSS path details are stored in MySQL.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection( 
  :adapter => "mysql2",
  ...
)

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :site_details

  def create_product_links
    # http://www.example.com
    p = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    p.xpath(total_products_path).each {|lnk| SiteDetail.find_or_create_by(url: url + "/" + lnk['href'], site_id: self.id)}
  end    
end

class SiteDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site   

  def get_product_data
    # http://www.example.com
    p = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    title = p.css(site.title_path).text
    price = p.css(site.price_path).text
    description = p.css(site.description_path).text
    update_attributes!(title: title, price: price, description: description)
  end 
end

# Execution
@s = Site.first
@s.site_details.get_product_data
```

I will be adding more sites (around 700) in the future. Each site have a different page structure. So `get_product_data` method cannot be used as is. I may have to use `case or if statement` to jump and execute relevant code. Soon this class becomes quite chunky and ugly (700 retailers).

What is the best design approach suitable in this scenario?

Comment: Is this a case where the user will select a retailer and you have to grab data from it or are you going to be running through 700 retailers to display data?

Comment: @JamesWoodward: No. There are no interaction from users involved. I manually insert retailers, xpath into db. I will be running all to display data.

Comment: I won't promise this is the best answer but I'd probably create a class for each retailer that implements get_product_data and returns it in a common format. Then use the Factory pattern to retrieve the implementation for the retailer you want to use. It will likely end up having a case/if statement in the factory but it will be contained and keep this particular class nice and clean. It may help if you but in something more to describe the overall plan. For instance. Will you just iterate over all 700 every time you display the page or maybe 300 in some cases?

Comment: All 700 will be iterated every day at a specific time.

Comment: There is never a best general way. There are the faster, and the best for maintability, and most likely you never need the best for a specific point. But there are many possibilities. You have to study the tradeoffs of each possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @James Woodward said, you're going to want to create a class for each retailer. The pattern I'm going to post has three parts:

1. A couple of `ActiveRecord` classes that implement a common interface for storing the data you want to record from each site
2. 700 different classes, one for each site you want to scrape. These classes implement the algorithms for scraping the sites, but don't know how to store the information in the database. To do that, they rely on the common interface from step 1.
3. One final class that ties it all together running each of the scraping algorithms you wrote in step 2.

### Step 1: `ActiveRecord` Interface

This step is pretty easy. You already have a `Site` and `SiteDetail` class. You can keep them for storing the data you scrape from website in your database.

You told the `Site` and `SiteDetail` classes how to scrape data from websites. I would argue this is inappropriate. Now you've given the classes two responsibilities:

1. Persist data in the database
2. Scrape data from the websites

We'll create new classes do handle the scraping responsibility in the second step. For now, you can strip down the `Site` and `SiteDetail` classes so that they only act as database records:

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :site_details
end

class SiteDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :site
end
```

### Step 2: Implement Scrapers

Now, we'll create new classes that handle the scraping responsibility. If this were a language that supported abstract classes or interfaces like Java or C#, we would proceed like so:

1. Create an `IScraper` or `AbstractScraper` interface that handles the tasks common to scraping a website.
2. Implement a different `FooScraper` class for each of the sites you want to scrape, each one inheriting from `AbstractScraper` or implementing `IScraper`.

Ruby doesn't have abstract classes, though. What it does have is duck typing and module mix-ins. This means we'll use this very similar pattern:

1. Create a `SiteScraper` module that handles the tasks common to scraping a website. This module will assume that the classes that extend it have certain methods it can call.
2. Implement a different `FooScraper` class for each of the sites you want to scrape, each one mixing in the `SiteScraper` module and implementing the methods the module expects.

It looks like this:

```
module SiteScraper
  # Assumes that classes including the module
  # have get_products and get_product_details methods
  #
  # The get_product_urls method should return a list
  # of the URLs to visit to get scraped data
  #
  # The get_product_details the URL of the product to
  # scape as a string and return a SiteDetail with data
  # scraped from the given URL 
  def get_data
    site = Site.new
    product_urls = get_product_urls

    for product_url in product_urls
      site_detail = get_product_details product_url
      site_detail.site = site
      site_detail.save
    end
  end
end 

class ExampleScraper
  include 'SiteScraper'

  def get_product_urls
    urls = []
    p = Nokogiri::HTML(open('www.example.com/products'))
    p.xpath('//products').each {|lnk| urls.push lnk}
    return urls
  end

  def get_product_details(product_url)
    p = Nokogiri::HTML(open(product_url))
    title = p.css('//title').text
    price = p.css('//price').text
    description = p.css('//description').text

    site_detail = SiteDetail.new
    site_detail.title = title
    site_detail.price = price
    site_detail.description = description
    return site_detail
  end
end

class FooBarScraper
  include 'SiteScraper'

  def get_product_urls
    urls = []
    p = Nokogiri::HTML(open('www.foobar.com/foobars'))
    p.xpath('//foo/bar').each {|lnk| urls.push lnk}
    return urls
  end

  def get_product_details(product_url)
    p = Nokogiri::HTML(open(product_url))
    title = p.css('//foo').text
    price = p.css('//bar').text
    description = p.css('//foo/bar/iption').text

    site_detail = SiteDetail.new
    site_detail.title = title
    site_detail.price = price
    site_detail.description = description
    return site_detail
  end
end
```

... and so on, creating a class that mixes in `SiteScraper` and implements `get_product_urls` and `get_product_details` for each one of the 700 website you need to scrape. Unfortunately, this is the tedious part of the pattern: There's no real way to get around writing a different scraping algorithm for all 700 sites.

### Step 3: Run Each Scraper

The final step is to create the cron job that scrapes the sites.

```
every :day, at: '12:00am' do
  ExampleScraper.new.get_data
  FooBarScraper.new.get_data
  # + 698 more lines
end
```